# 50 tries and 1 hasnt been the answer at all

Tags: java, random, netbeans

This is coded in Java 15.0.2 and on netbeans 12.0LTS
I would like to assume I coded this coin flip generator correctly but 0 is the only option that gives me correct, 1 never has. I don't know if I messed something up with Math.random or if i'm just that unlucky.

```java
package pkgthis.thing;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Student
 */
public class LabQuestion6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int coin = (int) (Math.random()*1);

        int choice;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please choose 1 or 0: \n");

        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if (choice == coin) 
        {
            System.out.println("You are correct");  
        } 

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You are incorrect");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Read the document of [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) first. Then try to print some value `System.out.println(Math.random());` to learn how the method works.

Comment: `int coin = (int) (Math.random()*1);`; Math.random() will be some value between 0 and 1, which you then multiply by 1.  That's the same thing, so it's still some value between 0 and 1.  Then you cast this to an int.  Going from a floating point number (a decimal) to an integer (not a decimal) in java always rounds towards 0, which is called truncation.  So this number will be 0, always.  Your bug is somewhere on that line.

Comment: [1] The [`nextInt(bound)` method of `Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) is a much better approach than using `Math.random()`. [2] As a separate matter, note that NetBeans 12.0 does not support the use of Java 15. [From the 12.0 release notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html): "_Apache NetBeans 12.0 runs on the JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 14, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release._"

Answer (score 4):

Math.random always gives a number greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1(exclusive). Converting it to int will always give you 0. An alternative to your approach could be:

`int coin = (int) (Math.random()*2);`

Comment: Or `nextInt(0, 2)`.

Comment: This issue has come up several times before on SO. Please check for duplicates before posting an answer.